# Typescript errors when using jest mocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a previously-created `.js` file that mocks away some of our functions for `jest` test purposes. I'm migrating that to a `.ts` file:

**Server.ts**

```
const Server = jest.genMockFromModule('../Server');

Server.getAsync = Server.default.getAsync;
// other REST-ful functions here

export default Server;
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Property 'getAsync' does not exist on type '{}'
>
> Property 'default' does not exist on type '{}'

Then, in a corresponding test file:

**MyComponent.test.ts**

```
import Server from 'path/to/Server';

jest.mock('path/to/Server');

const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
const getStateMock = jest.fn();

describe('MyComponent.someFunction', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it('Does the right stuff', () => {
        Server.getAsync.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve([{ key: 'value' }]));
        dispatchMock.mockImplementationOnce((promise) => promise);
        dispatchMock.mockImplementationOnce();

        return someFunction()(dispatchMock)
            .then(() => {
                expect(Server.getAsync).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                expect(Server.getAsync.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('something');
            });
    });
});
```

I am getting errors on `dispatchMock.mockImplementationOnce()`

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. (method)
>   jest.MockInstance<{}>.mockImplementationOnce(fn: (...args: any[]) =>
>   any): jest.Mock<{}>

...on `Server.getAsync.mockReturnValueOnce`

> Property 'mockReturnValueOnce' does not exist on type '(url: string,
>   baseRoute?: string | null, loadingGenerator?: (isLoading: boolean) =>
>   { type: strin...'.

...and on `Server.getAsync.mock`

> Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(url: string, baseRoute?:
>   string | null, loadingGenerator?: (isLoading: boolean) => { type:
>   strin...'.

I've been pounding my head on this for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Okay, I added `as any` to the end of the first line of my `Server.ts` file so now it looks like:

```
const Server = jest.genMockFromModule('../Server') as any;
```

That got rid of the first set of errors. Still facing the errors in my `.test.ts` file though.

**UPDATE 2**

I've noticed that when I run the actual jest tests, that they all pass even though there are TypeErrors. These issues don't appear to be related to actual tests.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I fixed this myself. The way that I got it to work was to cast any calls to `Server.getAsync` to the specific jest mock type.

```
let getAsyncMock = Server.getAsync as jest.Mock
```

or

```
let getAsyncMock = <jest.Mock>(Server.getAsync)
```

This gets rid of my errors.

Comment: Did you find out a way to do this with imports? ie: `import axios from 'axios'; jest.mock('axios');`

Comment: Awesome answer. I did like `(Server.getAsync as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce` under each unit test and it worked.

Comment: This does not work with the latest version of typescript. I have to cast it to unknown first. i.e `Server.getAsync as unknown as jest.Mock` Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 11):

Following the @nobleare response... a good update will be to wrap your mock implementation into the `beforeAll` and clear it into the `beforeEach` block:

```
import { AnalyticsApi } from "../../api/src";

jest.mock("../../api/src");

describe('...', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    (AnalyticsApi as jest.Mock<AnalyticsApi>).mockImplementation(() => ({
      listPolicies: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('promiseValue')
    }));
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    (AnalyticsApi as jest.Mock<AnalyticsApi>).mockClear();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that dude, the `(AnalyticsApi as jest.Mock<AnalyticsApi>)` or even `(AnalyticsApi as jest.Mock)` really helped me out!!

Answer (score 4):

Use [this](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md)

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { foo } from './foo';
jest.mock('./foo');


expect(mocked(foo)).toHaveLength(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

To override an import, you can do it like so:

```
import { AnalyticsApi } from "../../api/src";

jest.mock("../../api/src");

let listPolicies = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve();
});

(AnalyticsApi as jest.Mock<AnalyticsApi>).mockImplementation(() => ({
  listPolicies,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using `genMockFromModule` which creates a mock of your `Server` so there is no need to call `jest.mock('path/to/Server');`.

Second, what are you trying to achieve by doing `Server.getAsync = Server.default.getAsync;`? All that does is move the `getAsync` up a level which isn't necessary. You could just call `jest.genMockFromModule('../Server').default;`;

`dispatchMock.mockImplementationOnce()` is throwing that error because you said it requires a promise to be passed to it here: `dispatchMock.mockImplementationOnce((promise) => promise);`

For `Server.getAsync.mockReturnValueOnce` and `Server.getAsync.mock` you actually want to use `mocked` instead of casting the type like the other answers suggest.

Example: `mocked(Server.getAsync).mockReturnValueOnce()`