# Mocking generic functions with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I tried many ways to mock a generic function with jest, unsuccessfully. Here is the way that seems to me correct:

```
interface ServiceInterface {
    get<T>(): T;
}

class Service implements ServiceInterface {
    get = jest.fn(<T>(): T => {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    });
}
```

At compilation it throws the following error:

```
error TS2416: Property 'get' in type 'Service' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ServiceInterface'.
  Type 'Mock<{}, any[]>' is not assignable to type '<T>() => T'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Could you show me the correct way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I think, if you create a interface, let make it as a generic interface instead of setting up generic for each properties.

```
interface ServiceInterface<T> {
  get(): T;
}
```

When you create a mock with Jest:

```
class Service<T> implements ServiceInterface<T> {
  get = jest.fn<T, []>((): T => null);
}

const instance = new Service<string>();
const result = instance.get(); // typeof result === "string"
```

For your case, what you need to mock is return value of `get()`

```
interface ServiceInterface {
  get<T>(): T;
}

const mockedGet = jest.fn();

class Service implements ServiceInterface {
  get<T>(): T {
    return mockedGet();
  }
}

const instance = new Service();
mockedGet.mockReturnValue("Hello!");
const result = instance.get<string>(); // now, result is a string
```

Comment: Interesting approach but it doesn't fit my needs as I truly need generic functions.

Comment: pretty close but it will break the interface I currently use on my mocks. I'm used to call `mockReturnValue` directly on my mocked services. Maybe it's the Jest Typescript interface that doesn't allow what I want ?

Answer (score -4):

I use [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) for my mocking which can be installed using:

```
npm i sinon --save-dev
```

then to mock in one of your tests you could do something like this:

```
const mock = sinon.mock(service); // you want the value passed in to mock to be the actualy object being mocked
mock.expects('get').returns(null) // this would expect get to be called once and the return value is null
mock.restore(); // restores all mocked methods
mock.verify(); // verifies the expectations
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my initial question but this tool looks interesting. I will take a look.

Comment: @Max have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51251369/10513374)